# current tournament position on pokerstars mobile

Tags: tournament

I'm playing a tournament on a tablet on pokerstars app and I can't see which is my current tournament position. Is there any way to get that information?

On PC version is displayed on upper right corner of the table.

Comment: The PokerStars support team has a great reputation. You might ask them.

Comment: You'd very likely get a faster response from the Pokerstars support team. as Chris Farmer mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an email to the PS support team and they confirmed that the Android app doesn't have this information.

I could not find any place to request this feature to PS dev team.